# Attribute not creating using DomDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am stuck with `DomDocument`

This thing is working fine, no doubt -

```
$resource1->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('type'))
          ->appendChild($dom->createTextnode("webcontent"));
```

It is adding `type="webcontent"` to resource node

However when I am using this code its not adding it to it -

```
$resource1->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('adlcp:scormType'))
          ->appendChild($dom->createTextnode("sco"));
```

Expected to generate - `adlcp:scormType="sco"` <-- **Not Working**

However If I am creating 
`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` <-- **Working**

Code -

```
$manifestNode->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi'))
             ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong and how do I make it working

**EDIT**

Error -

> XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace

Googled same with the keyword - `xml parsing error prefix not bound to a namespace php` but not much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an attribute on a node:

```
$resource1->setAttribute('type', 'webcontent');
```

To set a namespaced attribute on a node (assuming this is the namespace represented by the "adlcp" prefix):

```
$resource1->setAttributeNS('http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2', 'adlcp:scormType', 'sco');
```